# Android XML different margin on long screen

Tags: android, xml, screen

Is there a way how to set a different margin for a XML view on long screens?

As soon as screen ratios are quite diverse, i need to set a top margin for a view only for long screens, such as Samsung Note II (1280x720) to display my XML properly.
Every opinion appreciated.

Comment: I think you should use `values/dimens.xml` file for different screens.

Comment: Is there a way how to include all long screens at one time? based on aspect ratio or something?

Comment: using more values folder you can apply different dimension(ex. text size, padding, margin etc) for different screen size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use different folder name for different layout. Like:

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation

res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density
```

[Read here for details](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create 4 different layouts to support multiple screen sizes..
Refer [Android Multiple screen support](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Using this you can set margin in larger layout

Comment: Oh there is a "aspect ratio" characteristic, thats something Ive been looking for, but Im still not sure how to link different layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Create separate folder named `layout-xhdpi` inside resource and define your appropriate xml with margin there, hope it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to work with relative layout with And put your Images in drawable  .so that your Image well Managed By itself. I have done that  something like this:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/logosmall"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/logo2" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```